# Merging cells automatically in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I want to merge the cells[green] in ArcMap as shown in picture below.

Is there any way to do it automatically instead of manually?

There are 200 classes and every time I need to merge the cells for each class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) tool to merge them together.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I applied dissolve tool but it works only for selected cells. every time again i need to select the new cells by using select by attributes menu bar, based on gridcode. is there any way to automatically select the grids based on gridcode and then merge them?

Comment: @SumraMushtaq ArcGIS tools always take into account your current selection. Clear selection and try again with "dissolve_field" as mentioned in the tools description.